# toFixed not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a saving price which is using the Math.ceil method to round up the output to the nearest £, however when I am implementing toFixed to give me £25.00, all I am getting is £25.

my code is as such:-

```
jQuery(function($) {
    var price = $('.product-info-short meta[itemprop="price"]').attr("content");
    var discount = price/10;
    var earlyBirdPrice = price-discount;
    var div = document.querySelector('.earlyBirdPrice');


//method for early bird price//
div.innerHTML += '<div class="earlyBirdPrice">Price: £' + 
Number(earlyBirdPrice.toFixed(2)).toLocaleString('en') + '</div>';

//method for discount price//
div.innerHTML += '<div class="discount"> Saving you £' + 
Number(Math.ceil(discount.toFixed(2))).toLocaleString('en') + 
'</div>';

});
```

js fiddle here:
https://jsfiddle.net/y18h9s7f/

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Why are you converting it back to number? Just `earlyBirdPrice.toFixed(2)` should be enough.

Comment: Be careful. You are converting to/from numbers/strings all over the place.

Comment: could you try it with var discount = parseFloat(price)/10; var earlyBirdPrice = parseFloat(price)-parseFloat(discoun)t;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:-

```
div.innerHTML += '<div class="discount"> Saving you £' + Number(Math.ceil(discount)).toFixed(2) + '</div>';
```

**Demo:-** https://jsfiddle.net/f18o1v91/

Comment: Thanks so much! Works perfectly!

Comment: @RobbieMcMullen, Kindly look T.J.Crowder answer.

Comment: @RobbieMcMullen: It works (as of the latest edit) **if** you don't want locale-specific handling of the number. I assumed from your question that you did.

Answer (score 6):

What you're doing wrong is that after converting to a string with `toFixed`, you're converting back to a number, and then calling `toLocaleString('en')` on that number.

You can *either* use `toFixed` to get a non-locale-specific string with the given number of decimal places, **or** `toLocaleString('en')` to get a locale-specific string with the default number of places, but not both.

You probably want to look at using `Intl.NumberFormat` ([spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-402/#numberformat-objects) | [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat)) if it's supported by your target environments (you can feature-test it and fall back to something else). Example:

```js
const formatter = typeof Intl === "object" && Intl.NumberFormat
  ? new Intl.NumberFormat('en', { // Yay, we have Intl.NumberFormat
      minimumFractionDigits: 2,
      maximumFractionDigits: 2
    })
  : {format: n => n.toFixed(2) }; // Boo, fall back. (Maybe something more intricate here.)
console.log(formatter.format(42.546789));
```

That outputs `42.55` because I'm using the `en` locale. If I used `de` for German, it shows `42,55`:

```js
const formatter = typeof Intl === "object" && Intl.NumberFormat
  ? new Intl.NumberFormat('de', { // Yay, we have Intl.NumberFormat
      minimumFractionDigits: 2,
      maximumFractionDigits: 2
    })
  : {format: n => n.toFixed(2) }; // Boo, fall back. (Maybe something more intricate here.)
console.log(formatter.format(42.546789));
```

This one uses the browser's default locale (e.g., user-specific):

```js
const formatter = typeof Intl === "object" && Intl.NumberFormat
  ? new Intl.NumberFormat(undefined, { // Yay, we have Intl.NumberFormat
      minimumFractionDigits: 2,
      maximumFractionDigits: 2
    })
  : {format: n => n.toFixed(2) };      // Boo, fall back. (Maybe something more intricate here.)
console.log(formatter.format(42.546789));
```

Comment: Typical answer as always

Answer (score 1):

You apply `Math.ceil()`/`Number()` on top of `toFixed()`, hence the result is a Number, not a float-string.

Answer (score 1):

You need to

- Remove the `Number` constructor wrapping
- Apply `Math.ceil` directly to `discount`

Make it

```
Math.ceil(discount).toFixed(2)
```

> all I am getting is £25.

Basically `Number` `constructor` will remove the decimals if there is only 0s after the decimal.

```js
console.log( Number( "25.00" ) );
var discount = 25.00;
console.log(Math.ceil(discount).toFixed(2))
```

Comment: That calls `toLocaleString` on a **string**, not the number. Presumably the point was to use locale-specific *number* settings.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder OP said *I am implementing toFixed to give me £25.00*, so I don't think `toLocaleString` is even required.

Answer (score 1):

You apparently need to remove the `Number` wrapping :

From :

`Number(Math.ceil(discount.toFixed(2))).toLocaleString('en')`

To :

`Math.ceil(discount).toFixed(2).toLocaleString('en')`

Answer (score 1):

Hey @Robbie I found your problem and solved it. You missed to apply parseFloat(). I change your code in jsfddl. please take look my solution.

```
//method for discount price//
div.innerHTML += '<div class="discount"> Saving you £' + parseFloat(Number(Math.ceil(discount.toFixed(2))).toLocaleString('en')).toFixed(2) + '</div>';
```

Here is JSfiddle link: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sajibremix/uj3qkd6r/) https://jsfiddle.net/sajibremix/uj3qkd6r/
I think you found your solution. Happy coding :)

Comment: Welcome brother.